# Getting multiple drop down list value from view in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am trying to use JSF to retrieve multiple drop down lists according to user input from the view to controller.

However seems I cannot find the correct way.

As the drop down lists are generated dynamically, I cannot hard code the id / name of the drop down list.

Here is my code in the view:

```
                    <ui:repeat var="file" value="#{uploadBean.filesInZip}" varStatus="status">
                        <tr>
                            <td><h:outputText value="#{file.name}" /></td>
                            <td>
                                <h:selectOneMenu id="studentSelections" value="#{uploadBean.studentSelections}" name="studentSelections">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{uploadBean.students}" var="student" 
                                        itemLabel="#{student.firstName}, #{student.lastName} (#{student.userId})" 
                                        itemValue="#{student.id}"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ui:repeat>
```

I thought I could declare a List named ***studentSelections*** in the controller so that I could get all the user input of the drop down list, but seems I have failed.

So could anyone give a hand on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I thought I could declare a List named studentSelections in the controller so that I could get all the user input of the drop down list, but seems I have failed.*

That's the correct model approach. In the view side, you need to reference the list value by index as available by `<ui:repeat varStatus>`. Assuming that `#{student.id}` is `Long` and you've a

```java
private List<Long> studentSelections;
```

then this should in your particular case do

```html
<h:selectOneMenu ... value="#{uploadBean.studentSelections[status.index]}">
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, [the `<h:selectOneMenu>` doesn't support the `name` attribute at all](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneMenu.html). Get rid of it. JSF autogenerates one.